# Chrome visualization problem CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I get forecast from Google Weather Api but there's a problem in Chrome if the temperature in Celsius is e.g. -4.The problem is that numbers are under - ,not near it.
You can view the page here(click on the cloud to see the problem) http://rssreaderbg.net/pubsubbub/example/cssexam/index.php

Comment: @I82Much ,oh,sorry.Edited.
@Gray - `position:absolute,top:25px,z-index:1,left:250px`
That's the css for the second forecast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `#utre`, `#udr` and `#audr` id's:

```
margin-left:-6px;
width:50px;
```

I could strongly urge you to move these style from `inline` to an external style sheet for maintainability and to prevent code redundancy and bloat.